# Sitefinity Custom Widget Error - The view 'Write.Default' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, telerik, sitefinity

I am new to SiteFinity and yet am writing a Custom Widget for Sitefinity. I have followed the documentation and process as described here:

https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/create-custom-designer-views-mvc

However, when I compile this custom widget and try to use it on a form, it throws an exception.

Upon looking into the Error Logs, it says as below:

```
Type : System.InvalidOperationException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
Message : The view 'Write.Default' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/MultipleChoiceExtendedField/Write.Default.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Write.Default.cshtml
~/Views/MultipleChoiceExtendedField/Write.Default.aspx
~/Views/MultipleChoiceExtendedField/Write.Default.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Write.Default.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Write.Default.ascx
~/Views/MultipleChoiceExtendedField/Write.Default.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Write.Default.vbhtml
Source : System.Web.Mvc
```

I have the views right where they are needed in the Mvc folder under ~/Mvc/Views/MultipleChoiceExtendedField folder.

According to the message, I have also tried to move the views outside of Mvc folder and onto the root folder as the links suggest, however the error remains the same.

I feel I am missing something very small.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Ashutosh

Comment: I believe there is some confusion here, because the link points to a custom designer view (which you don't necessarily need in a custom widget), but the error points to a custom form field element, so maybe if you tell us what do you want your widget to do we might be able to help.

Comment: I am trying to utlize a Multiple choice widget from the feather widgets (https://github.com/Sitefinity/feather-widgets) and extend it with some more properties in the model and some more fields in the view. The first step towards it is taking over all the code from the original widget and creating a new one, making it work. That's where I am stuck as of now. The widget shows up fine on the forms editing window, but when I drag and drop it on the form, this exception shows up.

Comment: So, it appears you want to extend the built-in multiple choice form field. That field simply renders a list of choices that are defined in the backend by the user. What kind of fields and properties you want to add to it?

Comment: I am trying to add a new field to every choice called "Score" so whatever option the user chooses, each option has a score/weightage attached to it. I am trying to build a survey sort of stuff, that would in the end of the form, provide a total of how much each user scored.

Comment: How and where are you going to store the Score value for each option?

Comment: I was hoping I could do a custom form field (probably extending Multiple Choice Widget) and have additional property in the Model for that.